# How to update a field with an array object field in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to update a field value with a nested array object field.

I have a document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e91c7d4249c4035086d6339"),
    "codigo" : "000002",
    "cnpjs" : [
        {
            "cnpj" : "00000000000000"
        }
    ],
    "descricao" : "PLANO SUPREME",
    "status" : "A",
    "tabpreco" : "005",
    "taxaadesao" : 0,
    "cnpj" : ""
}
```

I need to make something like this, but didn't works:

```
    db.planos.update({},
        { $set: { 'cnpj': 'cnpjs.0.cnpj' } },
        { multi: true, upsert: false }
    )
```

How to access the nested field in object array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MongoDB 4.2+, you can use the pipeline form of update with aggregation operators:

```
 db.planos.update({},
       [
         {$set:{cnpj:{$arrayElemAt:["$cnpjs",0]}}},
         {$set:{cnpj:"$cnpjs.cnpj"}}
       ],
       {multi:true}
)
```

Comment: It works! But correct the second $set with {$set:{cnpj:"$cnpjs.cnpj"}}